# Async method not returning immediately

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I am working from this solution:
[How to correctly write async method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864200/how-to-correctly-write-async-method)

However, the async method does not seem to return immediately, rather it takes a while. Here is the

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling DoDownload");
        var downloadTask = DoDownloadAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("DoDownload done");
        downloadTask.Wait(); //Waits for the background task to complete before finishing. 
    }

    private static async Task DoDownloadAsync()
    {
        WebClient w = new WebClient();

        string txt = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com/");
        Debug.WriteLine(txt);
    }
}
```

"DoDownload Done" is being printed before the download text, but it takes a while (I think it is waiting for the download to completely return to print it.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AD.Net No, what he has is correct, for what he's trying to do.

Comment: It all looks correct to me.  How long is it actually taking before "DoDownload done" is printed?  Could you use a `StopWatch` to time it?

Comment: Yes you're not awaiting the result, so "DoDownload Done" is being printed before the download text. and you can't await in `Main` method, you probably need another method.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel He *wants* it to be printed first.  That's the point here.  It isn't.  That text *should* appear almost instantly; it's what he's expecting, but he's claiming that it's not.

Comment: Perhaps some of the work is being done synchronously, before returning the Task. For example, it might do the DNS lookup on your URL and create the socket, only doing the socket send/receive portion asynchronously.

Comment: I'm getting some weird behavior, sometimes it takes 2 seconds, sometimes 11 seconds.

Comment: For a release build running without the debugger attached I get a delay of 30-40ms.

Comment: @victorswx As Gabe pointed out dns lookup, etc can take its own time, Does that matters? If yes you can wrap this is `Task.Run`

Comment: You are running this on a server OS, right?

Comment: Yes, I am. Does that affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation and expectation is correct. `WebClient::DownloadStringTaskAsync` does have some synchronous operations before the actual underlying `WebRequest::BeginGetResponse` is called, but very few. The only one I see perusing through the code that might account for this proxy discovery/negotiation. Are you behind a proxy by chance?

Comment: JIT warmup wouldn't explain [a 2-11 **second** delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888709/async-method-not-returning-immediately#comment31349613_20888709).  I generally won't ever have a delay perceivable by a human.

Comment: Ah, I did not see his mention of exactly how long it was taking 'cause it was buried in the comments. Yeah, no, JIT wouldn't explain that.