# UI Thread blocked in C# WPF App during Async Download

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have the following basic WPF app, where I want the content displayed in the text box. However, when I click on the button, the UI thread seems to be blocking. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as I grabbed this code from the Excercise files of a Pluralsight course.

The XAML and the code:

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncFetch.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button
            x:Name="getButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="75"
            Content="_Get Data"
            Click="getButton_Click"
            />

        <TextBox
            x:Name="dataTextBox"
            Margin="4"
            Grid.Row="1"
            />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code:

```
namespace AsyncFetch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void getButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient w = new WebClient();

            string txt = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");
            dataTextBox.Text = txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057926/why-does-webclient-downloadstringtaskasync-block-new-async-api-syntax-ctp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Async method not returning immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888709/async-method-not-returning-immediately)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't block the UI thread, and the technique is correct.

However, just because a method is Async, and returns a `Task<T>`, doesn't guarantee that the *entire* method (or any of it) will run asynchronously.

In the case of `WebClient`, the control won't return to the caller until after the request has been completely prepared and started.  With `WebClient`, I believe the URI preparation, including all of the DNS lookups, can happen synchronously and is required before the asynchronous portion (the actual request) begins, which can cause a delay before the request returns.